# How to change table view to right in and master view to left in Splitview controller in landscape right mode?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using splitview controller in landscape right mode, By default the table view comes in left(in landscape right). Does anyone help me to get that in right ? and the master view in left..thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 0):

This replacement for UISplitViewController can accomplish that.

https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController